# Ошибка Python: can't open file '3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

Всем привет! Знаю ответов на данную тему очень много, но я как новичок не могу найти ответа именно на свой вопрос(или не понимаю). Подскажите пожалуйста)

Учу Пайтон по Bite of Python .Нужно было скачать программу Komodo ввести код(Hello world), далее сохранить его в папку и как я поняла связать с программой Pyton.Вот такой текст :
"В Komodo Edit нажмите “Инструменты” –> “Запуск команды”, наберите python3 helloworld.py и нажмите “Выполнить”. Вы должны увидеть вывод, показанный на скриншоте ниже"

Но у меня выходит Ошибка Python: can't open file '3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

[image: Скриншот 1-Как надо, 2-Как я делаю,3-Расположение файла в папке].

Comment: Кривая [`IDE`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8). Советую писать код в каком-нибудь текстовом редакторе(`Notepad++`, обычный блокнот), запускать через консоль.

Comment: Убедитесь, что ваш файл лежит в каталоге **без** русских букв и пробелов. Конкретно здесь похоже на `Python 3.8` (видите пробел?)

Comment: Михаил, спасибо за 3 дня понятия в чем проблема , помог только новый редактор Notepad, который не выдает ошибку. А что значит кривая IDE?

Comment: 0andriy убрала пробел , но ошибка осталась. Ладно попробую работать на другом редакторе

Answer (score 2):

Решение - вместо `python3 helloworld.py`, я просто указал путь к этому файлу.

То есть мой файл лежит на диске `С` в папке `python` и поэтому я указал `C:\pythom\helloworld.py` (мой файл тоже называется `helloworld`).